# Cordova ignores bower_components on build

Tags: android, cordova

I'm trying to build my android app with apache cordova.
Unfortunately my application doesn't work well . It looks like cordova ignores my bower_components catalogue and everyghing looks very bad.

This is path to my bower components (doesn't work)

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/core-ajax/core-ajax.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-button/paper-button.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-input/paper-input.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-checkbox/paper-checkbox.html">
```

My Path to my css and img files (that works , the same structure)

```
<div><img src="../assets/images/icons/key/drawable-hdpi/ic_action.png"/></div>   
<div><img src="../assets/images/logo.png"/></div>
```

I changed my .apk file to .zip to check that structure is ok , everything looks fine. 
Below You can see screenshot from my app structure . You can see assets folder (css and img are there and everything from this catalogue works perfect)
But nothing works from bower_components catalogue.

My first page is

```
   <content src="/pages/login-page.html" />
```

And `config.xml`

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="io.cordova.hellocordova" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>App</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="/pages/login-page.html" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
</widget>
```

[image: Application Structure]